# CMH-test, multiple contingency tables, unpaired entries

Tags: chi-squared-test, count-data, contingency-tables

I have frequency data for 9 populations, divided into two groups, one of five populations and one of four.  I am interested in whether these two groups are different.

A classic way to analyse such data, I think, is a CMH test where, in my example, I could construct a 2 x 2 x k test, where k is 4 = number of pairs (i.e 4 pairs based on four population from each group).  Clearly, I'd be leaving a one population out to generate a 4 x 2 x 2 table from my nine populations.

While the CMH-test seems clear and straightforward for paired data and paired groups, I don't have pairs.  Instead, there are numerous combinations of 4 pairs that can be generated from the 9 populations; in fact, 120.  Thus, I end up, considering all 2 x 2 x 4 tables, 120 chi-square statistics, odds-ratio's and p-values.

The question is how might I summarize these outputs into "one" summary.  Perhaps a more formal question is "What is the distribution of a set of Chi-square statistics"?  Or, is there an alternative?